# Expectation how does $E[XY^2]=E[Y^2E[X|Y]]$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Given random variables X and Y show that $E[XY^2]=E[Y^2E[X|Y]]$

For the case that $X$ and $Y^2$ are independent I have $$E(XY^2)=E(X)(E(Y^2)= E(E(X|Y))E(Y^2)=E(E(X|Y)Y^2)$$ but I'm sure about the general case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean what if $X$ and $Y$ are correlated somehow?

Comment: @Chinny84 Yes. The question is "Given random variables X and Y show that.." it doesn't say they are independent.

Comment: That may be, but I didn't see that in your question. All I saw was "I'm sure about the general case". So forgive the confusion.

Comment: @Chinny84 No worries, I'll edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [tower property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Iterated_expectation_for_continuous_random_variables) of conditional expectation plus measurability of the random variable $Y$ given its own value.

$$ E[XY^2] =\text{(tower)}= E[E[XY^2|Y]] = (\text{measurable}) = E[Y^2E[X|Y]] $$

Comment: I got the first part, but is there another way to get to the last step? We haven't covered measurability in our class.

Comment: @User38 Delete the assumption regarding independence. Because $E[XY^2]=E[X]E[Y^2]$ if our rv's are independent. This was not the issue.

Comment: @zoli I've done that now. But I'm still not sure how to show that $E[E[XY^2|Y]]=E[Y^2E[X|Y]]$

Comment: @User38 Keep in mind that the vertical bar reads "given". Just use the simple rule that values of $Y$ may be considered "constant" in some sense when you are "given" $Y$. So you can write $E[XY^2|Y] = Y^2E[X|Y]$ in the same way you could write something like $E[XY^2|Y = 2] = 4E[X|Y = 2]$

Comment: @zoli Ohhh!! Thanks so much that makes perfect sense now.